# Unique Value validation using djangoforms on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, validation, django-forms

I am trying to validate the uniqueness of an email address in datastore. The problem is that this does not allow me to edit/update the entry (e.g. if I only want to change the display_name - see models.py below).

I am submitting a form build using djangoforms (with an datastore entry prefilled as I already know the key of the datastore entry):

```
    forms.UserForm(instance=db.get(db.Key(key)))
```

After submitting the form using POST method I get the details from datastore and associate these with the submitted form:

```
    entry = db.get(db.Key(self.request.get('key')))
    data = forms.UserForm(data=self.request.POST, instance=entry)

    if data.is_valid(): 
      ...
```

The form then validates using the following form class (in forms.py):

```
  from django import forms
  from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms
  import models

  class UserForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = models.AuthorizedUsers

    def clean_email(self):
      """Prevent duplicate email addresses."""
      if self.Meta.model.all().filter('email =', self.cleaned_data['email']).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Duplicate Entry: %s.' %
                                     self.cleaned_data['email'])
      return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

Using the following model (in models.py)

```
    class AuthorizedUsers(db.Model):
      """Base model class for storing user permissions."""
      email = db.StringProperty()
      display_name = db.StringProperty()
```

Any suggestions what I am missing here? How can I prevent the raising of ValidationError when just updating an entry? Keep in mind that I do want to prevent the adding of a new datastore entry with the same email address.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if your email field has changed before checking whether or not to validate it against all previous email addresses. Your clean method would be changed to:

```
def clean_email(self):
  """Prevent duplicate email addresses."""
  if 'email' in self.changed_data:
      if self.Meta.model.all().filter('email =', self.cleaned_data['email']).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Duplicate Entry: %s.' %
                                     self.cleaned_data['email'])
  return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

Comment: You are an absolute hero!! Thanks a million! That worked perfectly! Great to learn about the self.changed_data :)